# Inserting/adding from one arraylist into two arraylist

Tags: linq, arraylist

I'm looking a way to insert `arraylist` in two different `arraylist` with same number of items.
for an example:

I have ArrayList something like this

```
ArrayList mainArrayList = new ArrayList {1, 2, 3,4,5,6};
```

So what I want from mainArrayList to insert into two arraylist (arraylist1 and arraylist 2)

this is what i am looking to have in two arraylist:

```
ArrayList arrayList1 = new ArrayList {1, 2, 3};
ArrayList arrayList2 = new ArrayList {4, 5, 6};
```

I can do through `for loop` but i am sure there is better of doing this.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < mainArrayList.Count; i++)
 {
    if(arraylist1.Count <3) {
       arrayList1.Add(mainArrayList[i]);
    }
    if(arrayList1.Count >3)
    {
       arrayList2.Add(mainArrayList[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: First, don't use `ArrayList`, use `List<T>`, where `T` is the type to store (in this case `int`.) Once you do that, you can use the LINQ `Concat()` method to get what you want: `mainList = firstList.Concat(secondList).ToList();`

Comment: i updated my question... i think you got confused with my question. so what i am looking is from mainlist data i want two arraylist or list with equal data on in it in my case firstlist 1,2,3 and in secondlist 4,5,6 - hope i make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GetRange(from, length)`

```
ArrayList mainArrayList = new ArrayList { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

ArrayList arrayList1 = mainArrayList.GetRange(0, 3);
ArrayList arrayList2 = mainArrayList.GetRange(3, 3);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `List<T>` instead of `ArrayList` which is an old non-generic container. Then you can use [`GetRange()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c.aspx):

```
List<int> mainList = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

List<int> list1 = mainList.GetRange(0, 3);
List<int> list2 = mainList.GetRange(3, 3);
```